# What is a good name for a list?

Tags: list, naming-conventions

What do you think is a good name for a variable or parameter that represents a list (any list)? For identifiers of some other common types the choice is more obvious, like 's' for a string and 'a' for an array. The problem with 'l' is that it looks too much like I (capital i) or 1. The name ls is the best I have found so far but it is not as nice as a one-letter name. I have also seen 't' being used although I don't associate this letter with a list. How do you name your lists?

Edit: Since some people seem to have misinterpreted the question let me just clarify that I consider lists without any special interpretation, like a list parameter in a list API.

Edit II: This question is *not* about Hungarian notation. It's about short (one-, two- or maybe three-letter) identifiers occurring in generic contexts.

Comment: After your edits, this is subjective and argumentative. Use any identifier.

Comment: @Alexandre And so are any questions about naming questions

Comment: I think the question was grossly misunderstood by most of the readers. Which of course is mostly the author's fault. :) Also I think that the quest for a single-character name is too ambitious and, most importantly, impractical: there are only 26 characters in English alphabet - they won't get you very far. :)

Comment: I believe that a generic name "lst" might be the best answer: its association with "list" is easy to remember, it's short enough, and my own experience suggests that the chances of getting "lst" into some sort of naming conflict/ambiguity are very very slim (at least they are much smaller than the ones of "ls" - if only because there are 3 characters instead of just 2 :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in the items within the list, call it something like `objects`, `items` or `things` (If you really don't know/care what kind of things they are).

If what you care about is the fact that it's a list, and not about the things in a list, then `list` or `lst` or `mylist` should do.

Don't use 1 letter variable names for parameters unless it's something already idiomatic like `x,y(,z)` for coordinates, or the `i, j` in `for` loops.

Comment: I think this is good advice in general. In some languages though, there are some more one-letter identifiers which are idiomatic.

Comment: @August but if they were already idiomatic then you'd probably already know them.  Still if they're parameters I'm hard pressed to come up with something other than coordinates and things that carry over from math.  They certainly wouldn't be generic though, you'd know exactly what they represent.

Comment: There seem to be two different schools; if we consider a string length function, some would write the heading as 'string_length(s: string): integer' and some would write something like 'string_length(characterSequence: string): integer'. I belong to the former school. No absolute right or wrong in this case.

Comment: @August in that case I'd used `str`, but I do see your point and I wouldn't consider it bad code to see `s` used in that case even though it's not my preference.  Unless you care about and are acting on individual characters in the sequence, `characterSequence` I'd say is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Apple> apples;
```

or, if you have a few of them:

```
List<Apple> redApples, yellowApples, rottenApples;
```

Comment: You seem to have misinterpreted my question. I mean a list in the most generic context, like for instance a parameter in a list API.

Comment: @August: what you want is not answerable. Use any letter. I vote to close as subjective and argumentative (what your previous question was not).

Answer (score 2):

I usually call them `list`, but that's just me. (No, seriously)

Comment: That's a reasonable choice. It may be a problem though if you program in a case insensitive language and there is a type with the same name (in the same namespace).

Answer (score 2):

I usually name them by what they contain such as students, orders, items and so on.

Comment: You seem to have misinterpreted my question. I mean a list in the most generic context, like for instance a parameter in a list API.

Comment: @August:  I doubt he did.  Many modern (especially dynamic) languages don't encourage naming objects by a convention that implies their datatype.

Comment: @August Karlstrom Even in the most generic context there is no need to use the datatype in the name of the variable.

Comment: @Vincent So what name would you use for the parameter in a string length function?

Comment: @August If it accepts a string as a sequence of characters then I would call it characterSequence or expression or input_string or so. That is, describe the semantics of the parameter. The type is given by the other information available.

Comment: @Vincent With 'input_string' you use the datatype in the name, so 'input' would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

s for string, a for array is misunderstanding of hungarian notation http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html. Don't do it. It gives nothing but problems when You refactor. When You change types You have to rename variables and parameters.

Just name it so that You know what it holds. List of Balls is balls. That simple.

Comment: Hungarian notation is about adding prefixes to variable names. There is no prefix in a one-letter name.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. You are putting type info in name of variable. That's misunderstood Hungarian notation.

Answer (score 0):

*something*_list or at least anything that implies 'plural'.